# Java and Interfacing with Sony IP Camera

Tags: java, http, sony

I usually don't like to post questions because I would rather figure things out myself, but I am ready to pull my hair out with this one.  I am trying to interface with a Sony IP Camera using Java.  One of the products of the company I work for uses a Sony IP camera (IPela EP550).  I have been tasked with writing the new interface.  I can connect to the stream using the VLC ActiveX embedded control, but I can't manipulate the PTZ of the camera from in Java.  If I type: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/command/ptzf.cgi?Move=left,0" in a web browser it will move, but I have tried every bit of code I can find with Google to get it to move with no success.  This last thing I tried (because a page on Oracle said all I should have to do is open the connection):

```
URL url1 = new URL("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/command/ptzf.cgi?Move=left,0&t="+new Date().getTime());
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
```

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check out whether the camera needs login.
2. type the url in the browser, get `HTTP request header` and put header data into your code!

Comment: The camera only needs a login to change the setting when you are connected to it's main interface.  When you enter the URL as I typed it above (with the appropriate IP address), no webpage is return the action in the camera just happens.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this.  I am posting the solution in case anybody is looking to fix a similar problem.  I took the basic idea in [this Dr. Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/making-http-requests-from-java/240160966) and used it to get movement from the camera.  I don't yet know why I can't get the camera to respond with URLConnection and HttpURLConnection, but using a Socket and PrintWriter to specifically print the GET request to the socket.